# while parsing xml getting none type even it has some value,how can i solve this issue?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

**input**
As you can see guys the xml code that i am trying to parse ,has value in name then how can it be NoneType?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
input='''
  <stuff>
    <user>
      <user x='2' >
        <id>001</id>
        <name>chuck</name>
     </user>
     <user x ='7'>
       <id>009</id>
       <name>brent</name>
       </user>
     </user>
    </stuff>

     '''
stuff=ET.fromstring(input)
print(stuff.find('name').text)
```

**output**

```
AttributeError             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f10e349a116e> in <module>
     16      '''
     17 stuff=ET.fromstring(input)
---> 18 print(stuff.find('name').text)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct [xpath syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) to get to the sub-child name tag.

Try this:

```py
print(stuff.find('.//name').text)
```

Result:

```
chuck
```

Comment: can you please tell me what can i do if i want to print '' brent ''

Comment: You get to brent a couple of ways, one is to use `findall` and loop the results or you could specify the attribute of the user like - `print(stuff.find('.//user[@x="7"]/name').text)`. xpath is complex and worth digging into. See [here](https://gist.github.com/IanHopkinson/ad45831a2fb73f537a79) for some examples.